# The element type "activity" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</activity>"

Tags: android, xml

I have been trying to find out what went wrong with my mainfest file.
Can't fix it

any comments?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="au.com.itview.shell">
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label=""
    android:supportsRtl="true"/>
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 5):

You are closing your `application` tag with a `/` in the opening tag itself. Do this:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label=""
    android:supportsRtl="true">
```

Comment: am also found this issue.you comment before me,,anyway am given +1

Answer (score 1):

Proplem is you  closed Application tag before  Activity.Activity must be inside the Application tag.

use code

```
 <application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label=""
android:supportsRtl="true">
```

instead of

```
<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label=""
android:supportsRtl="true"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

you miss application name in Lable tag this was the mistake in your manifest file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="au.com.itview.shell">
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="Your App Name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"/>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    </application>
    </manifest>
```

Comment: Why is that needed?

Comment: because this name is visibile to user in applications list

Comment: Thats the `android:label` buddy. `android:name` is the path to your java class extending the `Application` class iff any.

Comment: i also taking about label not the name tag

Comment: Oh..well that shouldn't be a problem.